# Where is Ansible variables in Playbook located

Tags: ansible

This is just an example I found on Github:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  apt:
    name: '{{ packages }}'
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  vars:
    packages:
      - curl
      - software-properties-common
      - python3-pip
become: yes
```

My question is:
where is the `"{{ packages }}"` variable usually declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are typically declared in a `group_vars` or `host_vars` folder (see [the docs on "Best practices"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html)). But in your example, the variable is declared in the task itself. `"{{ packages }}"` is a list of three packages:

```
vars:
  packages:
    - curl
    - software-properties-common
    - python3-pip
```

Comment: Follow-up question: Since Ansible executes sequentially, shouldn't the `vars` be declared before `apt:`

Comment: Ansible executes tasks sequentially, but in this example everything is part of a single task, including the vars declaration. You can find more info on variables [in the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass it as an argument while running the playbook. 
For example:
This is your playbook

```
- name: Install dependencies
  apt:
    name: '{{ packages }}'
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
```

Then you can call your playbook with those params
`ansible-playbook installer.yml --extra-vars '{"packages":[curl, python3-pip]}'`